# Python builtin decorator that calls its argument?

Tags: python, closures, decorator, standard-library

What I am looking for is a function that calls its arguments, so that I can use it as a decorator to easily deal with closures. It's easy enough to write (if I cared I could even use `*args` and `**kwargs`):

```
def unclosure(f):
    return f()

@unclosure
def count():
    x = 0
    def _count():
        nonlocal x
        x += 1
        return x
    return _count

assert count() == 1
assert count() == 2
```

But I feel like this is such a simple idea that this *has* to be builtin to the python standard library somewhere. I've checked `functools` but I don't know where else to check, and I can't seem to find the right thing to type into google. Anyone know if/where this exists?

Comment: In addition to using a class, another approach is to use the `count()` function directly as a place to store a small bit of state. For example: `if not hasattr(count, 'x'): count.x = 0` etc. It's similar to the unclosure approach in that the state lives with an ordinary function. The unclosure hides the state inside the guts of the original, while the direct approach leaves the state fully exposed for anyone to see (admittedly, for good or ill).

Comment: @FMc I considered this, but I am actually currently using (and probably will continue to use) the default-argument trick. E.g. `def count(x=[0]): x[0]+=1; return x[0]` It has the side-benefit that you can temporarily override the value: `assert (count(), count([42]),count()) == (1,43,2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for is identical to<sup>1</sup> the [`apply`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply) function, which existed in Python from 1.0 to 2.7, but was deprecated since 2.3.<sup>2</sup>

In fact, you can use it that way in 2.7:

```
@apply
def count():
    x=[0]
    def _count():
        x[0] += 1
        return x[0]
    return _count
assert count() == 1
assert count() == 2
```

---

Why was it deprecated?

Python doesn't often need it. It's useful in functional languages when combined with other things that Python doesn't have, like a composition operator, for writing a style of code that doesn't read very Pythonically, and executes very slowly.

But before 2.3, that wasn't quite true. Trivial cases, you can just write it yourself: `lambda f: f()`, or `def apply(f): return f()`. But for non-trivial examples, before unpacking syntax, you couldn't do "perfect forwarding" for arguments, so you couldn't simulate every use of `apply`. That's why it was added. And, once it was no longer needed, it was deprecated.

A few people did complain that writing it yourself is slightly slower than having a C builtin—but nobody ever came up with a use case where that made a difference, but the extra function call indirection didn't already make the whole thing too slow to use in the first place. And if you look through the huge amounts of open source code written from Python 2.3-2.6, pretty much none of it uses `apply`. And nobody ever wrote and published a C extension to preserve or `apply` so they could keep using it. Nobody's written one for 3.x in the last decade, either.

When "Python 3000" (what became 3.0) was under discussion, one of the first things that came up with eliminating all of the deprecated functions. Which spread to include things that weren't deprecated, but Guido didn't see a need for, like `reduce`. You can read the mailing list archives to see that people came out to defend some functions and constructs, usually successfully—but I don't remember, and can't find, anyone trying to defend `apply`. The only discussion is the summary in [PEP 3100](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3100/#id105):

> `apply()`: use `f(*args, **kw)` instead [2]

… where the link points to (a broken link to) Guido's [Python Regrets presentation](https://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/regrets/PythonRegrets.ppt), which has no more argument than calling it a "relic".

---

<sub>1. Or, rather, a weaker version of `apply` that doesn't take any arguments.</sub>

<sub>2. IIRC (I can't find the relevant documentation), this happened before Python had a real notion of "deprecated". It was marked "non-essential" and moved to the end of the docs page, and only somewhere around 2.5 or 2.6 did it become retroactively deprecated since 2.3.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! I felt like i was going crazy because it felt like there should be a builtin, and it's good to know that there was, it's just gone now. At least I know what to name my custom function now! [=

Answer (score 4):

This would typically be implemented using a class, not a closure.

```
class Count:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    def __call__(self):
        self.x += 1
        return self.x

count = Count()
assert count() == 1
assert count() == 2
```

Comment: While I agree that this is the appropriate way to implement a counter, the example was intended as a minimum working example, not an actual use case. And while I'm sure one could use a class any where you can use use a closure, there's a reason python allows for closures.

Comment: Yes, but defining a closure simply to provide state for the inner function just doesn't fit Python's particular idiom (which is one reason why a seemingly simple decorator like `unclosure` isn't in the standard library).

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm aware, no such function exists in the standard library.

I suspect that the reason for this is the fact that there are hardly any use cases for such a function. Even your decorator actually isn't a good use case, because it's not a properly implemented decorator. As you can see, it doesn't maintain the function's name or docstring:

```
@unclosure
def count():
    """docstring"""
    x = 0
    def _count():
        nonlocal x
        x += 1
        return x
    return _count

print(count)  # <function count.<locals>._count at 0x7f3282dac620>
print(count.__doc__)  # None
```

Which means that in reality, it should be implemented like this:

```
import functools

def unclosure(f):
    func = f()
    functools.update_wrapper(func, f)
    return func

@unclosure
def count():
    """docstring"""
    x = 0
    def _count():
        nonlocal x
        x += 1
        return x
    return _count

print(count)  # <function count at 0x7f3892f7c620>
print(count.__doc__)  # docstring
```